# Snowflake sql Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am trying to create a procedure using sql in snowflake,but its giving an error when calling it.

```sql
create or replace procedure get_max_date( )
returns datetime not null
language sql
as
$$
begin
  set max_date= (select  max(last_updated) from Control_Variables);
  return max_date;
  end
$$;
```

> Error:SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 9 invalid
> identifier 'MAX_DATE'

please give me a solution ,actually i want to declare a variable inside proc and store data in that variable as shown in procedure

Regards,
Nadeem

Tried to create snowflake procedure

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to declare your variable inside the procedure. Try this:

```sql
create or replace procedure get_max_date( ) 
returns datetime not null 
language sql 
as 
$$
declare 
max_date datetime;
begin 
max_date := (select max(last_updated) from Control_Variables); 
return max_date;
end 
$$;
```

Example how it works with some test data:

```sql
create or replace table Control_Variables (last_updated datetime);
insert into CONTROL_VARIABLES values ('2022-11-28 23:59:59');
insert into CONTROL_VARIABLES values (current_timestamp());
call get_max_date();
```

[image]